# Tidy conditional replacement

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there a more *tidy* way to achieve the following?

```
d = data_frame(domain = c('http:news.com/', 'http:news.com/', 'http:news.com/'),
               url = c('http:cnn.com/article/123', 'politics', 'economics'))

d %>% mutate(url = {
  f = !str_detect(url, '^http'); # filter
  replace(url, f, paste0(domain[f], url[f]))
})
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  domain         url                     
  <chr>          <chr>                   
1 http:news.com/ http:cnn.com/article/123
2 http:news.com/ http:news.com/politics  
3 http:news.com/ http:news.com/economics
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just easier to do a `case_when`

```
d %>% mutate(url = case_when(
  !str_detect(url, '^http') ~ paste0(domain, url), 
  TRUE~url))
```

or just an `if_else`

```
d %>% mutate(url = if_else(!str_detect(url, '^http'), 
  paste0(domain, url), 
  url))
```

Comment: Thanks I think `if_else` is best

Answer (score 0):

A *tidy* way in base R:

```
idx <- !grepl('^http', d$url)
d$url[idx] <- do.call(paste0, d[idx,])
```

which gives:

> ```
> > d
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>   domain         url                     
>   <chr>          <chr>                   
> 1 http:news.com/ http:cnn.com/article/123
> 2 http:news.com/ http:news.com/politics  
> 3 http:news.com/ http:news.com/economics
> ```